# Undefined is not an object for 2D array

Tags: javascript

I have this block of code where I'm looking for a value in a 2D array:

```
function subSquare(y, x, half) {
  var a = y - half;
  console.log(terrain[a][x]);
}
```

Which keeps returning this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'terrain[a][x]')

If I typeof a it is a number. Not sure why its not working. Thanks

Comment: Either `terrain` is undefined, or `terrain[a]` is undefined.  The error is not indicating that `a` is undefined.  We can't offer any more than that without a [mcve].

Comment: and what about x ?

Comment: @zb22 If `x` were undefined, it would not throw that error.

Comment: well. `terrain[a][x]` means it's looking inside of `terrain[a]` for `x`, and since `a` is a number, not an object or array, there's no way that's going to work.

Comment: @zfrisch Your analysis is incorrect.  It is looking inside of `terrain[a]` for `x`.  It is not looking inside `a`.  Member access is evaluated from left to right.

Comment: haha @Amy good call. That _is_ what I meant, but I didn't express it well.